# OAUTH issues with twitteR package

Tags: r, oauth

I am using R and want to use the twitteR package available on CRAN.

I installed the twitteR package using:

```
install.packages(twitteR)
```

then loaded the package with:

```
library(twitteR)
```

after that I wanted to run the first command to get the latest trends on twitter with:

```
getTrends(period="weekly")
```

which showed following error:

```
Error in getTrends(period = "weekly") : 
argument "woeid" is missing, with no default
```

Also the command:

```
searchTwitter("#orms")
```

showed an error, namely:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1
```

And also for the command:

```
userTimeline("informs")
```

there was an error output:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1
```

What is the reason for that? From my research so far I figured out, it has something to do with oauth. But actually I don't know, what oauth is, and how to configure it, so I can properly use the twitteR package.

Could please anybody provide me some help for this issue??

Thank you very much in advance for your support.

With best regards!!!

Comment: Read the **twitteR** documentation. The examples demonstrate how to configure OAuth, which you need to do before trying to interface with twitter. If you have any trouble with that process, there are many many questions on SO that address it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1/ You'll need to load ROAuth, which is a dependency of twitteR. See the twitter CRAN docs. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf

```
Depends: ... ROAuth (>= 0.9.3) ...
```

2/ You'll need to authenticate as per the below. See pg12 of the twitteR CRAN docs:

```
## A real example, but using a fictitious consumerkey and consumer
## secret - you’ll need to supply your own
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "12345pqrst6789ABCD"
consumerSecret <- "abcd1234EFGH5678ijkl0987MNOP6543qrst21"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
requestURL=reqURL,
accessURL=accessURL,
authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake()
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
```

In general, you should try to search error messages over the CRAN docs of your package - the answer will often be self-contained.